# Getting tags in Git Push on pre-receive

Tags: git, github, githooks, gitlab, git-bash

I'm using `pre-receive` hooks in GIT (using bash on Linux) to filter the push that are allowed into my repo.

I need to filter the push that developers do into my GIT repo, allowing just pushed with this requisites (`#` is number):

- `# Commits > 0 && # Tags != 0`: NO
- `# Commits > 0 && # Tags == 0`: YES
- `# Commits == 0 && # Tags > 1`: NO
- `# Commits == 0 && # Tags == 1` && `Key is correct`: YES

Consider branches and other operations same as commits. You can only push a single tag using the right key (specified in tag comment). You can't push a tag with other elements.

The problem is that `$refname` only have the HEAD ref, so if you do this order:

1. `Commit`
2. `Tag` (to any revision, even oldies)
3. `Commit`

The `$refname` will point to the last reference (i.e. `/refs/heads/master`), so doing:

`if [[ "$refname" == "refs/tags/"* ]]; then
 ...
fi`

Won't work in the order mentionated. I tried to iterate through references using `rev-list` and `for-each-ref`, without success.

How could I process the push being received, knowing the number of tags (and getting the comment of each one) to satisfy the upper conditions?

PS: Consider also the situation of pushing with --all option, receiving more than one branch.

Comment: Is there a good reason to do this? Even if you do somehow get it to work, it won't prevent a developer doing `git push origin master && git push origin mytag`.

Comment: commits==0 && tags==0 is not in your list -- just sayin'

Comment: @Ben: we'll let do the tags only trough a front end made by us. It must not be unbreakable, but must prevent mistakes letting pass only the given cases.

Comment: @remram: it would be: YES    :)

Comment: It's for a production server, not homework.

Comment: It might be more productive to describe why you want this particular behavior.